# Creating running and installing windows services - How to appropriately send a control request to the SCM

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, c#-4.0, service

I've been struggling with this windows service now for almost two weeks, I have scoured the internet for a resolution and in the process I have learned a lot except that I have not been able to resolve my issue.

I can't seem to find the right way to compose and run a service. There are some articles and opinions on this question even on SO but most of the questions on SO don't even have an acceptable answer, I'm hoping my question will be better accepted by the community so we can settle this windows service issue once and for all.

First of all I have set my configuration mode to debug on x86 (Internal reason for this). I have an installer class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practique
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer1 : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public Installer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //# Service Account Information
            serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

            //# Service Information
            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Practique";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

            //# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name
            //# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Practique";

            //S.Nsibande - Add service description.
            serviceInstaller.Description = "Practique - application is for testing how I should send control messages to the SCM in best practice manner so as not to get stupid errors on start and stop control requests to the Microsoft OS.";

            this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }
}
```

My entry point into my service application is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practique
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            #if DEBUG
                Service1 myService = new Service1();
                myService.OnDebug();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
            #else
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]{ new Service1() };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

And then the logic performed by my service is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practique
{
    //Service class inheriting from the ServiceBase class
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        //Two required overides... OnStart() and OnStop()
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            log.Source = "Application";

        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
            System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log.txt");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message + ".Stack trace - " + ex.StackTrace);
            if(ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                log.WriteEntry(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
        }

        private void ServiceStatus()
        {
            // Toggle the Practique service - 
            // If it is started (running, paused, etc), stop the service.
            // If it is stopped, start the service.
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Practique");

            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log.txt";

            // Open the stream and write to it.
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
            {
                Byte[] info =
                    new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("The Ptractique service status is currently set to " + sc.Status.ToString() + ".");

                // Add some information to the file.
                fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            }



            if ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) || (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
            {
                // Start the service if the current status is stopped.
                // Open the stream and write to it.
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
                {
                    Byte[] info =
                        new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Starting the Practique service...");

                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }


                sc.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                // Stop the service if its status is not set to "Stopped".

                // Open the stream and write to it.
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
                {
                    Byte[] info =
                        new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Stopping the Practique service...");

                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }
                sc.Stop();
            }

            // Refresh and display the current service status.
            sc.Refresh();
            // Open the stream and write to it.
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
                {
                    Byte[] info =
                        new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("The Practique service status is now set to " + sc.Status.ToString() + ".");

                    // Add some information to the file.
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I might have made some very stupid basic mistake, but that is all the code on my application. And on debug, it runs just fine, it does what it is expected to do. But once installed successfully using a batch file with the following instructions:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
 "C:\Programming\Test\Practique.exe"

 Pause
```

My question which I hope will be answered by someone that has been creating and using windows services successfully for a long time, is why does my service keep causing the following error:

This is the information from event viewer after a successful install:

> A service was installed in the system.
>
> Service Name:  Practique Service File Name: 
>   "C:\Programming\Test\Practique.exe" Service Type:  user mode
>   service Service Start Type:  demand start Service Account: 
>   LocalSystem

Then when I attempt to start the service, I get the following error in event viewer:

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the
>   Practique service to connect.

And...

> The Practique service failed to start due to the following error:  The
>   service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely
>   fashion.

Then I also get this popup when trying to start the service:
[image: Picture of the services error message popup]

---

Please tell me if my approach is wrong, have I missed a basic principle here, what have I done wrong or have I done too much. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

---

(Edit) - I am compiling in Debug mode, although I have tried release mode just in case there might be a difference, but this did not help.

Comment: Just to check, you are definitely compiling in RELEASE mode for your install?

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)` - what did you expect? That an infinite operation would somehow return in under 30 seconds?

Comment: With the code you have you _must_ compile in RELEASE mode to install your service: the SCM requires a response from your service that it has started _before_ the service starts doing any work: when your service is compiled in DEBUG mode it starts working straight away.

Comment: Looks like you are right @stuartd please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks a million.

Comment: That System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite) only runs during debug @iinspectable that's what the #If Debug is for, the code would otherwise ignore that block if not debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you have you **must** compile in `RELEASE` mode to install your service: the SCM requires a response from your service that it has started *before* the service starts doing any work: when your service is compiled in `DEBUG` mode it starts working straight away, so never reports back to the SCM, thus resulting in the error.